# Why is "dig localhost" so much quicker than "nslookup localhost"?

Tags: localhost, nslookup, dig

When looking up the address for `localhost`, `nslookup localhost` takes ~15 seconds:

```
$ /usr/bin/time nslookup localhost
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

Command exited with non-zero status 1
0.00user 0.00system 0:15.00elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 4072maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+1121minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

`dig localhost` is immediate.

```
$ /usr/bin/time dig localhost

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.17-Ubuntu <<>> localhost
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 20936
;; flags: qr aa rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;localhost.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
localhost.      0   IN  A   127.0.0.1

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Wed May 09 08:53:37 UTC 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 43

0.00user 0.00system 0:00.07elapsed 6%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 4244maxresident)k
320inputs+0outputs (1major+1164minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Why is `dig` so much faster than `nslookup`? What is `nslookup` doing / `dig` not doing that takes so long?

Incidentally:

```
$ grep localhost /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

The fact that `nslookup` is failing is down to a configuration issue: `/etc/resolv.conf` contains an extra `search` suffix, which is being forwarded to a non-existent resolver.

**My question is: why the difference?**

Comment: In your own output nslookup is failing so that isn't a meaningful comparison. For me both commands are near instant.

Comment: `dig` and `nslookup` both take around 10ms for me. as @jdwolf pointed out, your output shows that `nslookup` is timing out, hinting at a configuration issue.

Comment: I know it's a configuration issue. My question is why the difference? I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

In your particular case, it's because `nslookup` is timing out, which usually takes a very long time compared to getting a valid response.

As a bit of further background:

- `dig` is mostly a low-level debugging tool.  It doesn't do recursion by itself, requires you to specify a server to query, and lets you query arbitrary RR types (or just `ANY` to get all the records`)  It's generally going to be marginally faster doing the actual lookup than nslookup simply because it has all the data it needs on the command-line.
- `nslookup` is designed to be an interactive tool for querying DNS infrastructure, instead of inherently doing spot-lookups like `dig` does.  It happens to provide a non-interactive mode (which you are using above), but that's mostly just shorthand.  While you can tell it to use a specific server, it will default to using ones configured in `/etc/resolv.conf`, and thus the startup without a server specified is marginally slower than `dig` (because it has to look in a file).
- `host`, which you didn't mention, but is worth mentioning here for completeness, is a command provided by the C library for doing hostname lookups.  It uses the name resolution routines in the C library, which means that it honors `/etc/resolv.conf`, but it also will honor settings in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, which means it may look up hostnames in `/etc/hosts`, via NIS or NIS+, via LDAP, via mDNS (if you use the right TLD for this), via LLMNR, or through any number of other means,  As a result, it's slow compared to `dig` and `nslookup`, but it also shows you exactly waht a program that's using the system's name resolution settings instead of doing it's own DNS will see.